# How to pass a property of the MainViewModel to other ViewModels and notify it when this changed in a MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i am new in programming and especially in MVVM Framework. I want to make WPF application using the MVVM Framework but i'm stacked in a problem of passing the value of a property (SupportPath) of the MainViewModel to the others ViewModels and notify when that changes.

Here is an example of what i want to do:

This is my MainWindow with a TextBox at the top that holds the SupoprtPath property (string) of the MainViewModel that i want to pass to the other ViewModels.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_SwitchingViews.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_SwitchingViews"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MVVM_SwitchingViews.Models"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Foldername:"/>
                <TextBox Width="600" Margin="3" Text="{Binding SupportPath,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Margin="10" Width="200" Content="Protokoll" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="Protokoll"/>
            <Button Margin="10" Width="200" Content="MillProtokoll" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="MillProtokoll"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     private SupportPathModel _supportPathModel;
     public SupportPathModel SupportPathModel
     {
         get { return _supportPathModel; }
         set
         {

             _supportPathModel = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SupportPathModel));
         }
     }

     private string _supportPath;
     public string SupportPath
     {
         get { return _supportPathModel.SupportPath; }
         set
         {
             if (string.Equals(value, _supportPathModel.SupportPath, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
             {
                 return;
             }
             _supportPathModel.SupportPath = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SupportPath));
         }
     }

     private BaseViewModel _selectedViewModel;
     public BaseViewModel SelectedViewModel
     {
         get { return _selectedViewModel; }
         set
         {
             _selectedViewModel = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));
         }
     }

     public ICommand UpdateViewCommand { get; set; }

     public MainViewModel(SupportPathModel supportPathModel)
     {
         _supportPathModel = supportPathModel;
         UpdateViewCommand = new UpdateViewCommand(this);
     }
 }
```

ProtokollViewModel.cs

```
public class ProtokollViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  
    private string _protokollPath;
    public string ProtokollPath
    {
        get { return _protokollPath; }
        set
        {
            _protokollPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProtokollPath));
        }
    }

    public ProtokollViewModel()
    {
             

    }

   
}
```

I have read that can be done with MVVM Light using Messengeror or with  Prism using event aggregator, but for me is difficult to use them . Can that be done using an Action and invoke it ?

Here is an example what i mean:

SupportPathModel.cs

```
 public class SupportPathModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     public Action<string> OnSupportChanged;

     private string _supportPath;
     public string SupportPath
     {
         get { return _supportPath; }
         set
         {
             _supportPath = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SupportPath));
             OnSupportChanged?.Invoke(_supportPath);
         }
     }



 }
```

And then subscribe that Action in the ProtokollViewModel and raise that when fires. I

Can someone please help me how can i achieve that?

Thnx in regards

I put an Action in the class SupportPathModel.cs but i could call it from the ProtokollViewModel

Comment: MVVM is not a framework. MVVM is a design pattern. You should google the difference. How is the relationship between ProtokollViewModel  and MainviewModel? Does MainViewModel creates ProtokollViewModel? from your code ProtokollViewModel  has no relationship to neither MainViewModel nor SupportPathModel

Comment: Messenger or eventaggregators are usually used in a different context, to solve a different problem. You don't need any messenger. You likely have to correct your class design.

Comment: @BionicCode Code design flaws aside, messengers such as the WeakReferenceMessenger are a valid way to notify subscribers such as other ViewModels about changes. Ideally, ViewModels don't know anything about other ViewModels, except for child ViewModels, which often should just be a model class, though.

Comment: @Julian *"ViewModels don't know anything about other ViewModels, except for child ViewModels"* - Exactly what I said. That's the general relationship between the classes that participate in composition. Whether the class is a view model or model doesn't matter in this case. The moment your child classes depend on the parent class, your design is very likely flawed. You could use a kind of messenger to hide that dependency - or fix your class design.

Comment: @Julian *"design flaws aside"* - The design flaws are the key. The reason to resorting to such messenger related patterns. They will unnecessarily complicate your simple code. That's why one should always fix the class design before falling back to more complicated solutions. Fancy patterns don't fix smelling code.

Comment: @BionicCode I am aware and I agree. I also didn't argue against that, that's actually why I wrote exactly that. Messengers are generally valid for MVVM, but they can indicate that there may be a design flaw (depending on the relationships between classes). And yet, they can be used to resolve such problems, even if that's a more "dirty" way. It's up to the OP to decide whether a refactoring of the dependencies or a quick fix is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the ViewModels and Views in Dependency Injection. At Starting the Application you can set the DataContext. After that you can easy access to the single ViewModels if the Method or Property is Public.

It Looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<View>();


private readonly MyViewModel _viewModel;
private readonly View _view;
private 
public void MainViewModel(MyViewModel viewModel, View view) 
{
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    _view = view;
}
public void OnSetTextOnMyViewModel(string text) 
{
    //Use the Propertie of the other ViewModel which is registered.
    _viewModel.TextBlockValue = "...";
    //You also can create on 'MyViewModel' a method to set the Text and
    //invoke the OnPropertyChanged event to notify that something has 
    //changed.
    _viewModel.SetText("...");
}

//method on MyViewModel
public void SetText(string value) 
{
   //TextBlock Value is binded on .xaml in View
   TextBlockValue = "...";
   OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBlockValue));
}

//OnPropertyChanged Method
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string 
    propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
//if you want to set it if the value has changed to this:
//this is the property
public string Value 
{
    get => _value;
    set 
       {
           _value = value;
           _viewModel.TextBlockValue = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
}
```

Maybe this can help.

Good luck!